# Beginning C programmer - irritating error using for loop over array entries

Tags: c, arrays

I've attempted to write a program that will take an array of numbers, and produce a new array
containing the squares of the entries of the first array. Here is the function which is supposed to do this;

```
void square_entires(numbers, squares){

    for (int i=0; i<5; ++i) {
        squares[i]=numbers[i]*numbers[i];
    }

}
```

Now I get 3 errors on the `squares[i]`... line saying

```
"Subscripted value is neither array nor pointer".
```

Why on earth would I want `i` to be an array or a pointer!? Shouldn't it simply be an index for the loop to make sense? I've seen other examples of functions which loop over array elements this way and they work fine.. just my function doesn't work properly! Can somebody please explain why this is? thanks it advance.

Comment: It's not the index that the error is about, it's about `numbers` and `squares`.

Comment: How would the compiler now that e.g. `numbers` is an array if you don't tell the compiler it is? And an array of what type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your functions declaration is wrong. You must have to specify the types of the arguments in a function. It should be

```
void square_entires(int numbers[], int squares[]) 
{
```

Without specifying type of parameters, it will be considered `int` by default which is allowed in C89.

### n1570: 6.5.2.2 Function calls

> **Each argument shall have a type** such that its value may be assigned to an object with the unqualified version of the type of its corresponding parameter.

---

> Now I get 3 errors on the squares[i]... line saying
>   "Subscripted value is neither array nor pointer".
>   Why on earth would I want i to be an array or a pointer!? Shouldn't it simply be an index for the loop to make sense?

Clearly this warning is about the variables `squares` and `numbers` which should be declared either an array or pointer. Only then subscripted value is used.

Comment: ... unless you want plain `int` types, if the type is left out that is what they default to, just like functions.

Comment: Actually the function definition is wrong - we have no idea what the OP has declared the function as. The problem is with sub-script operator expecting an array, or even a pointer which you did not mention.

Comment: @technosaurus; But we do not rely on default argument type.

Comment: Also the answer does not explain - the fact that the datatype defaults to `int`

Comment: ^Only in C89 not in C99

Answer (score 3):

Given `A[B]`, the "subscripted value" is `A`. `B` is the subscript.

And, what others said about the missing type specifiers and declarator bits.

When you write:

```
int foo(a, b)
/* <- nothing here */
{
}
```

you're writing an old-style function. It's how C was written before some improvements took place in the 1980's which became standardized as ANSI C.  The types for `a` and `b` are declared between the function declarator and body. If they are not declared, evidently they default to `int`. There are two ways out. The much preferred one is to use the modern style:

```
int square_entries(int *numbers, int *squares) // or some other type: double?
{
}
```

The obsolete style, not recommended, would have looked like:

```
int square_entries(numbers, squares)
int *numbers;
int *squares;
{  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`[]` is the Subscript operator. The expression within the brackets is referred to as a subscript. A postfix expression followed by an expression in `[ ]` (brackets) specifies an element of an array.

You have not specified the types for `numbers, squares` in

```
 void square_entires(numbers, squares) // Defaults to type int (where actually you need type int array
```

This (*is valid in C89*) `main()` implicitly meant (previously) `int main(void)`. However the default return type rule has been abandoned in *C99*.

I think you need this:

```
void square_entires(int numbers[], int squares[])
```

or

```
void square_entires(int * numbers, int * squares)
```

Cause array decay into pointers in functions, hence you cannot calculate the size of the array in the function - so pass the sizes as well (if required), like this:

```
void square_entires(int numbers[], int squares[], int sizenumbers, int sizesquares)
```

By definition, the expression `a[b]` is equivalent to the expression `*((a) + (b))`, and, because addition is associative, it is also equivalent to `b[a]`.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an argument to a function, the argument should represent the type of the parameter you are going to pass. Here, when you see your passed arguments i.e. numbers and squares, it doesn't make it clear that what is the type of the data you are going to pass to your function.

Well, you are going to pass an array which contains the int data type, that is the reason why you need to declare your argument as an int array i.e. int numbers[] (where in the subscript [] represents that your argument is going to be an array and "int" represents that the array contains the data of int type".)

so, your code should be like :

```
void square_entires(int numbers[], int squares[]) 
{
```